# Apache2 "caching" my pages, while I don't have cache installed

Tags: php, cache

just to know, I am not a system admin (*I mean this is not my job*), and I try to configure my apache just to produce my projects.

My system is `Ubuntu 15.04` and I have installed `Apache2 Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)` with `PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2`.

The problem that I have, is that my files getting cached, whitout using any cache plugin for my site or any server side caching.

I don't know if the Apache comes with any default caching, and I don't even know how to search for it.

To give an example of my problem:

Lets say I create a file called `index.php` with the following content:

```
echo "Hello";
```

then, if I browse the file I will see of cource the word `hello` on my browser.

Now let's say I modify the code inside the file `index.php` into the following content :

```
echo "Hello World";
```

and then go to browse the file. This time, continue to display the hello. I totally clean the browser cache, I refresh with `Ctrl + R` many times, and still the same result.

Finally when I do in my console :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and then refresh my browser the content is the `Hello World`.

I don't know how to debug this problem, and if you need any further information about it, please tell me to provide you with what ever is required to help you.

So, can someone help me please ?

**UPDATE 1**

Here you can find my phpinfo(); export : http://jsfiddle.net/xebeou4n/

Comment: Your export clearly shows you have [memcache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04) installed and configured.

Comment: Xaxaxaxa !!! That's perfect, but I didn't new that :) Can you instract me how to disable it ? Or even better, is there a way to disabled through the .htaccess ?

Comment: Also, the one downvoted my question, did he read what I wrote ?

Comment: It depends on the version of memcached and the install folder, but it should be as straight forward as `make uninstall`. Looking around [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140086/remove-memcached-from-ubuntu) should give you some results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your posted PHP configuration, you have PHP's opcode cache module installed and enabled - this module replaces PHP's APC cache in PHP 5.5 onwards.

Change the following settings in your `php.ini` file:

```
opcache.enable = 0
opcache.enable_cli = 0
```

For more detail on the new opcode module , check the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just open my php.ini and I found the lines you describe. The lines was both commented out. So I remove the `;` character at the beggining of the line, and set the value to `0` but after apache restart, still I have the same problem :(

Comment: Ok, I removed the comments and also I disable the memcache from the htaccess too. Thanks a lot ! :)